# How to append HTML element multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, object, dom

I've added an event to my app(clicking & enter), the main goal of it is to add an input value every time the user uses that event, everything works just fine in the first shot but after that, the code stops to work, so please could you give me any suggestions or possible solutions?

this is my js code :

```
// important vars 
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const inputV = document.getElementById('input').value;
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const todoUl = document.createElement("ul");
const todoLi = document.createElement("li")
const todoList = document.getElementById('todolist'); // this the div that contain ul and li
const form = document.getElementById('from');

// this function is for add input value and create list's 
function addTodo(todo) {
    form.appendChild(todoUl);
    todoUl.appendChild(todoLi);
    todoLi.innerText = inputV    
};

// later ..
form.addEventListener('submit' , (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    addTodo()

});
```

update :
thank you all for your answers <3;

Comment: Can you share your HTML code and all your flow. It works, there is an another problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`appendChild` method appends a Node to the elements childlist, but **also removes it from the original place**. By the first call, it is not in the DOM yet, so it appends. In the later call, it is removed and re-added to the DOM, so effectively nothing happens.

If you want to append it multiple times, you need to [clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) it. In your case:

```
todoUl.appendChild(todoLi.clone(1)); // 1 = deep
```

If you just want to append `li` item, you probably don't want to clone/add the `todoUl` element in the subsequent calls.